# Python - UnicodeDecode Error - Resolving

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, ascii

I am having an issue with Python 2.7.x and `UnicodeDecodeError`...

First, this is text only, runs in the background to control a board that receives some data.

Second, since its text only, that means `ASCII` only. No I am not interested in what might be needed to display something in something other than English or anything else. `A-Z,a-z,$$@#$!,0-9` etc. that is ist.

This error vexes me as I am not sure what character, which must not be visible is the issue..

Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/XX/yyyy/MyPython.py", line 406, in
    mainProgram();
  File "/home/XX/yyyy/MyPython.py", line 150, in mainProgram
    getStatus();
  File "/home/XX/yyyy/MyPython.py", line 268, in getStatus
    msg = msg + "\n\n" + AlertText
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 194: ordinal not in range(128)

program closed out
```

This comes from this line:

```
msg = msg + "\n\n" + AlertText
```

I get AlertText from some code as follows:

The part that is causing the issue appears to be the text that comes in from:

```
html=urllib2.urlopen('http:/x.y'+Myevent+'&format=TXT&version=1&glossary=0').read()
          soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
          y=soup.find('pre') #returns data between <pre> tags.
          for a in y:
           AlertText = a.string
        print AlertText
        msg = msg + "\n\n" + AlertText
```

The AlertText PRINTS on the console (I keep a running log from the screen session, and can see the text come in and read it fine) just fine... it is python whining about encoding nonsense that doesn't want to merge the two strings.

I do NOT CARE about UTF-8 or what ever else.. the world is strictly `A-Z/a-z/0-9/$@` etc. to me...

I've looked at something like:

```
cleanstring = AlertText.decode('ascii','ignore')
```

Same )(@*$)(&$(*!@&$( ! errors about ascii can't decode... DUH! I told you to ignore that crap!! :mad:

Same with:

```
import re
AlertText = re.sub("[^A-Za-z]", "",AlertText)
```

Any hints on how to disable this checking and tell python to just merge this stuff ignore encodings or force strip everything to ASCII and move along! :)

Or something to clean it up..

```
stringx = asciime(stringx)
```

a `try|except` thing to catch this error won't solve it if I can't get AlertText cleaned up or python to quit getting in such a tither over stupid encodings that it should not worry about to start with! URRGRGHH! :mad:

I tried several things from other answers here, but just keep getting the same "can't decode " nonsense...

Any ideas to resolve this???

Comment: You want to **encode**, not decode. `AlertText.encode('ascii', 'replace')` or `AlertText.encode('ascii', 'ignore')`.

Comment: First this is NOT A DUPLICATE, as NONE of the so called answers work for me. Second,doesn't matter encode, or decode  still refuses to do this. Just errors and whines about can't encode or decode... some character, well just ignore it then! How do I beat python in to this mode, disable uni nonsense I don't want or need. If you need it great, I don't and it is cauing nothing but headaches.